# JUnit exception "Object is not an instance of declaring method"

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have the next JUnit test, but when I execute it throws "Object is not an instance of declaring method".
What could it be?

```
@Test
    public void testCopiarByteArray() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String expected = "prueba";
        String mensaje = "prueba";

        DataReader datareader = new DataReader(null, null, 100, "=");

        Method copiarByteArray = datareader.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("copiarByteArray", byte[].class, int.class);
        copiarByteArray.setAccessible(true);

        byte[] copia = (byte[]) copiarByteArray.invoke(mensaje.getBytes(), mensaje.getBytes().length);

        String actual = new String(copia, "UTF-8");

        assertEquals("failure - encription not correctly encript", expected, actual);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `.invoke` should be an instance of the object to invoke the method on.

So instead of:

> ```
>     byte[] copia = (byte[]) copiarByteArray.invoke(mensaje.getBytes(), mensaje.getBytes().length);
> ```

You need to add `datareader` as first parameter:

```
    byte[] copia = (byte[]) copiarByteArray.invoke(datareader, mensaje.getBytes(), mensaje.getBytes().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the javadoc on reflection APIs.

You have to pass the **object** to call your method **on** as first parameter; and then followed by the "actual" method parameters.

Your code tries to execute a method on `mensaje.getBytes()`; which of course will not work.